# Generate a list of files from a file containing a series of globbing patterns

Tags: zsh, wildcards, mercurial

I am looking for a way to build a list of files by parsing a file that contains a sequence of `zsh` globbing patterns.

The final goal is to pass this list of files to  `hg add` in mercurial. For those interested in this specific part, my question is motived by this other question that I asked in StackOverflow:

- [Mercurial “hginclude”? (globbing syntax to specify which files to track)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492035/mercurial-hginclude-globbing-syntax-to-specify-which-files-to-track)

A sample file (let's call it `.hginclude`) would look as follows:

```
.zshrc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.zprofile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
.less*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
.emacs*/**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
src*/**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.hg*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
.bash*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
.inputrc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
.ssh
```

and the output from the script should be a list of **files** obtained by collecting the output of

`print globbing_pattern`

on every line, where `globbing_pattern` refers to each line in the file `.hginclude` above.

Ultimately, the list of files should be a list that I can pass to `hg add` to track those files in mercurial.

The assumption for this part is that I have an `.hgignore` with the following:

```
syntax: glob
*
```

which means: don't track anything unless explicitly added via an `hg add` command.

Answer (score 4):

See [hg help patterns](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#patterns). Mercurial supports reading file names from a file, so you can do

```
$ hg add listfile:myfiles.txt
```

and have `myfiles.txt` contain the file names to add. What's even more interesting for you is that a "file name" in Mercurial can be a glob pattern. So you can have `myfiles.txt` contain

```
.zshrc
.zprofile
glob:.less*
glob:.emacs*/**
```

etc, and the `hg add` command above will do the right thing.

You can even use [file sets](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#filesets) to select the files. This is a `find`-like language that lets you do things like

```
set:exec() and not binary()
```

to select executable files that are not binary, i.e., scripts.

---

The above commands *will* respect the `.hgignore` file and so you cannot use them directly to solve your problem. However, you can use

```
$ hg status --all --no-status listfile:myfiles.txt
```

to get a list of files matches by the patterns, including any files that would normally be ignored. You can then proceed to use this file list with `hg add`:

```
$ hg status -A -n -0 listfile:myfiles.txt | xargs -0 hg add
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. This looks exactly like what I need. One problem I noticed is that if I have `syntax: glob *` in my `.hgignore` (as I explained in the original post) then `hg add listfile:myfiles.txt` does not add the files, whereas if I them one by one, e.g. `hg add .zshrc` it works. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes, I just checked the source and unfortunately, patterns are implemented so that they respect the `.hgignore` file. I did not think of that when I gave the answer. I'll raise the issue on the mailinglist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 hg add `for i in `cat myfiles.txt` ; do ls $i ; done`
```

where myfiles.txt contains the globs.
But of course the suggestion of initrpc is cleaner.